# Unable to add json file to couchdb

Tags: json, database, bash, couchdb

I'm new to couchdb and I want to populate my database using Git Bash. I made a text document with the following:

```
{
  "_id" : "_design/example",
  "views" : {
    "foo" : {
      "map" : "function(doc){ emit(doc._id, doc._rev)}"
    }
  }
}
```

I named it design.json and in Git Bash I type `curl -X PUT http://<username>:<password>@localhost:5984/testdb/_design/example --data-binary ‘@design.json’`

My problem is that instead of adding the file to my database I get a warning:

> Warning: Couldn't read data from file "design.json", this makes an empty POST.

followed by an error:

```
{"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you posted plus the `curl` call work for me – but of course only if I change the `‘...’` smart quotes from your posting to `'...'`. In the absence of another reason to fail, I suggest this is the problem.

Comment: Which quotes specifically are you referring to? I'll try to change them and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: The quotes around @design.json. In your post there are smart/typographic quotes, but you have to use simple quotes.

Comment: I tried using different quotes and I'm still unable to get it to work. I'm not sure why other people are able to get it to work while I'm not.